# k6 simulate logged in wordpress user

Tags: wordpress, k6

I am trying to simulate a logged in user activity for stress testing a WordPress site using this script:

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { sleep } from "k6";

export default function() {
  var url = "http://example.com.com/wp-login.php";
  var payload = JSON.stringify({ user_login: "admin", user_pass: "adminpass" });
  var params =  { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
  http.post(url, payload, params);

  console.log(payload);

  http.get("http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php")

  sleep(1)
};
```

This doesn't work and I am redirected to the login page.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/itsmejasbirsingh/k6-woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Wordpress internals, but looking at a few random installations' `wp-login.php` page, it doesn't look like it accepts a JSON string as the POST data, but rather a plain `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request: `http.post("http://example.com.com/wp-login.php", { user_login: "admin", user_pass: "adminpass" })` (though the field names were different).

To be sure, you can log in with a browser and then export the HAR file with the HTTP requests it made and convert it to a k6 script with the HAR converter in k6 by running `k6 convert exported.har`. You can find more information about that [here](https://docs.k6.io/docs/session-recording-har-support)

Comment: https://github.com/itsmejasbirsingh/k6-woocommerce